# UseEffect not called in child component after parent state update in Enzyme test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a click event using Enzyme and Jest. I have a parent component with `[isX, setIsX] = useState(false)` that is passed into a child component. The child component has:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");
    async function A() {
        if (isX) {
            ...
        }
    }
    A();
}, [isX])
```

I have a button in the parent component that calls `setIsX(true)` on click and I have confirmed that the test executes that code with console.log. However, in the child component useEffect is never called. I am using enzyme for the test. The wrapper is initialized with:

```
const div = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(div);
const wrapper = mount(component, { attachTo: div });
...
```

(the attachTo is necessary for a separate reason) and then I simulate the click.
I've tried enzyme's `wrapper.update()` but the console.log in useEffect never shows up. I am new to React/enzyme, and any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I've confirmed that the props do change in the child component after calling `wrapper.update()` but useEffect still not called.

Comment: Consider running tests in the browser instead. You'll eliminate all differences between browsers and jsdom, actually be able to debug your tests, and spend a lot less time figuring out why tests aren't working. I use Mocha. For CI/CD pipelines, I run Mocha tests headlessly using Karma. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai

Comment: Can you also show the entire code of the parent component? Or if it's very large, at least all parts of it where `isX` is referenced.

Comment: Well I've confirmed that the following console.log occurs:
`console.log("BUTTON CLICKED\n"); setIsX(true);`